# Update/Set Default Headers in the Curl

Tags: linux, api, curl

I have a scenario in which I call multiple API requests with the same headers.
Headers would usually have:

```
Authorization: Bearer ASADFW&YUWFIANDJDDAjd8sa87sad7sa8dhsahdusabhdw
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
etc...
```

I need to set these headers key-value pair as a default so whenever I curl the APIs these get picked.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just keep a text file open with the Curl command, something like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ASADFW&YUWFIANDJDDAjd8sa87sad7sa8dhsahdusabhdw"
             -H "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8" -d 'blah'
             http://some_url.com:8080
```

Then, just copy and paste the above into a terminal and make the changes you want.  Note that I have formatted the above on multiple lines for reading purposes only.  In practice, the entire Curl command should be on a single line.